# How to set input text color when defining a theme?

Tags: flutter

I define my theme as follows:

```
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
        .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
    canvasColor: secondaryColor,
  ),
```

How can I also change the color of text in TextFields? Do I have to modify the copyWith() call somehow?

Edit: I think I have a special case, because I'm using Flutter Login, I'm not sure if that changes things.

Comment: Have a look at InputDecorationTheme https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme-class.html

Comment: InputDecorationTheme doesn't seem to have any properties to set the text color. It seems to be for the control and not the text in it.

Answer (score 2):

TextFields use `subtitle1` text style by default, so the first way to change text color is to set `subtitle1`'s style:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
          ),
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: TextField pink]

You can also specify style overrides directly from TextField's `style` parameter:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: pink text]

---

I tried Your code and it works fine for me:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme()
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white)
            .copyWith(subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
        canvasColor: Colors.grey[800],
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
```

[image: purple text]

In terms of performance, `copyWith` is a lot lighter than `apply` because it doesn't have to recreate all styles.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me, unless I put the style on the Widget itself (similar to your 2nd example). I would like this setting to work with the example code I gave in my question.

Comment: You can try replacing `subtitle1`'s text style from the google fonts TextTheme. I updated my answer. Hope it also works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work for me. Only setting a theme for the exact screen works.